# Laravel saving ordered list of eloquent models

Tags: laravel, model, drag-and-drop, eloquent, sorting

I'm creating a food menu which the administrator can order/sort by dragging and dropping. This menu consists of multiple categories (ProductCategory) and products (Product).

I'm using [HTML5Sortable](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable) on the client-side to allow nested d&d. The markup is pretty simple:

```
<div class="categories">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="category">
        @foreach($category->products as $product)
        <div class="products">
            <div class=""product" data=id="{{ $product->id }}">
                 {{ $product->name }}
            </div>
        </div><!-- /products !-->
        @endforeach
    </div><!-- /category !-->
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And the corresponding javascript:

```
$('.categories').sortable({
    items: '.category'
});
$('.products').sortable({
    items: '.product'
});

// Will be called when the user is done repositioning the products and categories
function getOrderedList() {
    var data = {};

    $('.categories').find('.category').map(function(i) {
        var category = $(this);
        data[i] = {};
        data[i].id = category.data('id');
        data[i].products = category.find('.product').map(function() {
            return $(this).data('id');
        }).get();
    });

    data = JSON.stringify(data); // Send data to server
}
```

The function `getOrderedList` will send a JSON string back to Laravel, which contains the sorted category id's and product id's:

```
{"0":{"id":1,"products":[2,3,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},"1":{"id":2,"products":[11,12,13,14]},"2":{"id":3,"products":[15,16,17,18]}}
```

How would I make this work on the back-end? I guess I must store this array somewhere in the database and later find and order the models by the id's?

In short: What is a clean and flexible solution for sorting (nested) models (within Laravel)?

Answer (score 7):

A common convention is Weight, add a field called (Int)Weight on the products table, which is used to define the order of the items.

Once a change in the order occurs you only update the weight field.

When you retrieve the items, you sort them by Weight.

it becomes similar to an Array

```
Id        Name            Weight
01        'product 1'     2
02        'product 2'     0
03        'product 3'     1
```

when you order it by weight you get

```
product 2
product 3
product 1
```

it's similar to an array because

```
$products[0] = 'product 2'
$products[1] = 'product 3'
$products[2] = 'product 1'
```

Note that if you want to make it even more **dynamic**, you can create a polymorphic model that can satisfy multiple models.

Please refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Polymorphic Relations example

Create table **Weights** (migration example)

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('value');
$table->integer('weightable_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('weightable_type');
```

Create model **Weight**

```
class Weight extends Eloquent
{
    public function weightable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

now with any other model

```
class Products extends Eloquent
{
    ...
    public function weight()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Weight::class);
    }
}
```

this way you can just add that method to any model you want then you can sort your model with it.

**P.S. make sure any model that uses it, creates that relation immediately after creating the model**

**i do not recommend this method, it's much better if you explicitly define the weight field in the Products table, i understand how much you want your code to be dynamic, but everything comes at a cost**

**Performance goes down, it's not easy to visualize your code once you establish polymorphic relations, its more like starting to use Jumps instead of Functions**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew this. I guess I'm actually looking for a polymorphic solution where the 'Weight' column wouldn't be stored in the Product model itself, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I will edit the answer to include the polymorphic solution in a bit

Answer (score 2):

First, the JSON that you are producing shouldn't be an object where the keys are just array indices.  Instead it should be an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"products":[2,3,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},{"id":2,"products":[11,12,13,14]},{"id":3,"products":[15,16,17,18]}]
```

Since the `products` table to `product_categories` table has an obvious many to one relationship, you'd just use the *product_categories_id* foreign key on the `products` table to represent the relationships laid out in your JSON.

In the nested objects of your JSON, every value in the *products* key array will have a foreign key that corresponds to the *id* key value in the same nested object (this is the *product_category_id* column on your `products` table).

Your API endpoint function would then look something like this:

```
public function myApiEndpoint(){

    $input = Input::get('input');
    $input = json_decode($input, true);
    foreach($input as $category){
        Product::whereIn('id', $category['products'])->update(array(
            'product_category_id' => $category['id']
        ));
    }

}
```

I am updating the model directly in the API controller here, but you should really do any model changes through a repository that's also implementing an interface.

The above will work if you only ever have one menu (with it's categories and products).  If you want multiple menus, then you'll need a `menus` table along with a three way pivot table (with columns `menu_id`, `product_id`, and `product_category_id`).

Comment: You're updating the `category_id` within the product model, I don't see how this relates to my 'sortable' question.

Comment: @JasonK You're asking how to save a combination of products and categories that the user chooses.  If you're asking a different question, you should really go through and modify how your phrased your question

Answer (score 1):

I just implement this behavior using this library:
https://github.com/spatie/eloquent-sortable

It is very simple to implement, basically you need an extra column to keep the order and the library will do the rest, here is a part of the documentation:

- Implement the Spatie\EloquentSortable\Sortable interface.
- Use the trait Spatie\EloquentSortable\SortableTrait.
- Optionally specify which column will be used as the order column. The default is order_column.

use Spatie\EloquentSortable\Sortable;
use Spatie\EloquentSortable\SortableTrait;

class MyModel extends Eloquent implements Sortable
{

```
use SortableTrait;

public $sortable = [
    'order_column_name' => 'order_column',
    'sort_when_creating' => true,
];

...
}
```